# My jQuery .ajax script doesnt place html in div

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I've got problem, when I click ".page" button the content of news.php script doesn't appear in "#newsdiv". Firebug doesn't says there some errors, when I run news.php in my browser it easily gives me data from MySQL so it's js fault and I can't find where I made mistake, can someone help me?

Just wrote some code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
        $('a.page').click(function() {
            var value = $(this).text();
            var result = null; 
            var scriptURL = "/ajax.executable.files/news.php?page=" + value; //url for ajax
            $.ajax({
                url: scriptURL,
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'html',
                async: true,
                success: function(data) {
                        $('#newsdiv').html(data);   
                } 
            });
        });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');
    mysql_select_db('xxx');
    mysql_query('SET NAMES \'utf8\'');
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
    mysql_query("SET collation_connection = utf8_polish_ci");
    
    if(isset($_GET['page'])){
        $page = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']);
    }
    else{
        $page = 1;
    }
    
    $page = $page - 1;
    $ile = 2;
    
    $od = $page * $ile;
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM xxx LIMIT $od, $ile";
    $sql = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        ?>
        <div class="newsholder">
                <div class="newsheader">
                    <h1><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h1>
                    <h2><?php echo $row['subtitle']; ?></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="newscontent">
                    <div class="<?php $result = $id % 2; if($result != 0){ echo("rightsideimg"); } else{ echo("leftsideimg"); } ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="<?php $result = $id % 2; if($result != 0){ echo("leftsidesontent"); } else{ echo("rightsidecontent"); } ?>">
                        <?php echo $row['content']; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="newsfooter">
                    <div class="newsgooterright">
                        <div class="button">
                            Czytaj wiecej
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="newsgooterleft">
                        <small>napisal <b><?php echo $row['author']; ?></b> dnia 26-11</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
    }
    
    
    
    
    

?>
```

And php for making buttons

```
<?php
                    $offset = ceil($count / $ile);
                    for($i = 1; $i <= $offset; $i++){
                        echo("<a class=\"page\" href=\"javascript:void(0);\"><div class=\"page\">" . $i . "</div></a>");
                    }
                ?>
```

All files are placed like:

root/index.php with elements to click

root/ajax.executable.files/news.php with php script

root/jscripts/news.js with js for using news.php

Its all files which script is using

Comment: Did you look at the request / response info in Firebug?

Comment: Look at the console in Firebug and it will show you what was sent and received. You'll see POST requests, expand them for details.

Comment: Then its just blank, nothing is wroten

Comment: After you run the Ajax by clicking on the link? If nothing is there then you have another problem somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You have to `return false;` inside the click event, otherwise the click propagates up the hierarchy and if there is any HREF value (or even if empty), it will end up reloading the page.

So, after `$.ajax({...});` do a `return false;` and things should be fine.

EDIT:

Change the above script to the following and see:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('a.page').click(function() {
        var value = $(this).text();
        var scriptURL = "/ajax.executable.files/news.php?page=" + encodeURIComponent(value); //url for ajax
        $.ajax({
            url: scriptURL,
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'html',
            async: true,
            success: function(data) {
                    $('#newsdiv').html(data);   
            } 
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

ANOTHER EDIT:

Since you have a `<div>` inside the `a` tag, the `value = $(this).text()` will actually return a value of `<div>1</div>` instead of 1. So, remove the `<div>` tag as well and make the last code section as follows:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $offset; $i++) {
    echo("<a href=\"\" class=\"page\" onclick=\"return false;\">".$i."</a>");
}
```

That should make sure the ajax url is `..../news.php?page=$i`.

Comment: ive made javascript:void(0); it desnt work like return:false?

Comment: No it doesn't. If you have `<a href='#' onclick='javascript:void(0);' class='page'>Link</a>` then it will try and go to the anchor #.

Comment: but it looks like echo("<a class=\"page\" href=\"javascript:void(0);\"><div class=\"page\">" . $i . "</div></a>");

Comment: Change that to `echo("<a class=\"page\" href=\"\" onclick=\"return false;\">".$i.</a>");`. No need for the "div" inside the `a` tag.

Comment: maybe ill show u website with it? its www.radiolevel.xaa.pl the buttons are right below slider

Comment: You should style it at `a.page` instead of `div.page`. Or, put the `div` as the outer element to `a` and then style it as `div > .page`. Or if you really need to keep the `div` inside the `a`, then the `var value = $(this).text();` should change to `var value = $(this).children('div:eq(0)').text();`

Comment: Did you make both the changes mentioned in the answer above. (See EDIT and ANOTHER EDIT sections). Also did you try to go to the URL `/ajax.executable.files/news.php?page=1` directly to see if it is working? BTW, your website is inaccessible.

Comment: it doesnt work if i add /ajax.executable.files/news.php?page=1

Comment: Where does your `news.php` reside? That is the URL you need to put there.

Comment: its in public_html/ajax.executable.files/news.php

Comment: so theres no way to help me?? :(

Comment: Please edit your question to add all the relevant files and the hierarchy from the root of the webserver. That way, I will be able to follow which page is going where.

Comment: added it on bottom of my question check

Comment: Please check the server error logs to see if the PHP `news.php` has thrown any errors.

Comment: but if i run news.php it runs normally

Comment: Did you run the news.php with the page ID? Try both `/ajax.executable.files/news.php` and `/ajax.executable.files/news.php?page=1` and see the results.

Answer (score 0):

Make the following change -

```
$('a.page').click(function(event) { // pass event to the function
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action of the click
    var value = $(this).text();
```

Clicking the link is taking you to a new page, that is why there are no results in your console and why the div doesn't gey populated.

Comment: $(document).ready( function() {
  $('a.page').click(function() {
   event.preventDefault();
   var value = $(this).text(); and doesnt work
   var result = null; 
   var scriptURL = "/ajax.executable.files/news.php?page=" + value; //url for ajax
   $.ajax({
    url: scriptURL,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'html',
    async: true,
    success: function(data) {
      $('#newsdiv').html(data); 
    } 
   });

  });
});

Comment: maybe ill show u website with it? its www.radiolevel.xaa.pl the buttons are right below slider

Comment: You don't understand what changes I want you to make?

Comment: I cannot get to your website, it is blocked.

Comment: hmmmm it isnt, idk why it says like this